# nmcli: How to get the "last used" connection

Tags: command-line, network-manager

I'm trying to configure an auto wifi connection script for a remote system.  You can connect to saved connection with this command:

```
$ sudo nmcli c up "connection name"
```

There are occasions where the available networks might change... or other details such as the password might change.  If that happens, a person having access to the computer would manually make a new connection to the available wifi network.

Now I have need for my script to pick the profile starting with the most recent (`Last Used`) when the system is rebooted.

This command shows the available connections:

```
$ nmcli connection show
```

Now I'm looking for a way to sort the output by the `Last Used` order.

You can see this information using the GUI interface: [image: Network Connections]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `con` object has both a `TIMESTAMP` (seconds since epoch) and a `TIMESTAMP-REAL` field; probably the former is easiest to work with. For example, you could output the `NAME` and `TIMESTAMP` and then `sort` and `tail` the result. In terse mode, the fields are colon-separated by default, so you will need to set `sort`'s field separator accordingly e.g.

```
nmcli -t -f NAME,TIMESTAMP con list | sort -t: -nk2 | tail -n1
```

If you want just the connection name, either `cut` or `awk` it using the same separator

```
nmcli -t -f NAME,TIMESTAMP con list | sort -t: -nk2 | tail -n1 | cut -d: -f1
```

or

```
nmcli -t -f NAME,TIMESTAMP con list | sort -t: -nk2 | tail -n1 | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```